# Jquery Post not reaching MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Apologies if this i trivial, i have read many other comments and still cannot see what is wrong. I have done a few tutorials and they seem to work ok, so I am really missing something simple.

I have a basic 'remove' link that i want to do a JQuery Post back to the controller to remove an item from the database and then update the view.

My View / Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

        if (id != '') {
            $.post("@Url.Content("~/Agent/Remove")", { "id": id }, function (data) { alert('Here i am'); });
        }
    });
});
```

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Object) {
<tr id="row-@item.ID">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.ID" >Remove</a>
    </td>
</tr>
    }
```

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Remove(int id)
    {
        return Json(new { Data = "true" });
    }
```

Any assistance will be great.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response cycle using your console tools?

Comment: Sure that's the right URL? I would use `@Url.Action("Remove", "Agent")`

Comment: Also, check your javascript console, make sure there are no errors with your javascript

Comment: I have tested your code and it work fine. I added a breakpoint in the controller action and it was hit with the correct value. Please inspect your generated HTML and ensure `data-id` has a correct value, if a valid `int` is not passed as `id` then the action will not be hit

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Url.Action("Remove", "Agent")` instead.

`@Url.Content("...")` is used to locate any static content of the site.

Cheers

Comment: @nemesv: Actually, the action name is the first param, and then the controller name. I see your edit ;-)

Comment: Close... too many speech marks (or too little depending on how you look at it). Also, are you sure this is the reason for OP problem? There is a reason I posted as a comment

Comment: While `Url.Content()` is definitely not intended for generating action URLs, it's still likely to be generating the correct URL in this case, so this probably won't fix the problem.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy: That was my concern, I am not in a position to confirm this at the moment though

Comment: This answer is definitely wrong, I have just tested both ways and they both produce the same resulting URL string

Answer (score 0):

Below code works well.

```
   @foreach (var item in Model.Object) {
    <tr id="row-@item.ID">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="RemoveLink"  id="@item.ID" Value="Remove" />

        </td>
    </tr>
        }

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.RemoveLink').live("click", function () {
            Remove($(this));
        });
    });

    function Remove(_this) {

        var Id= $(_this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Remove", "Agent")',
            data: "{id: '" + Id + "'}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //do something here......
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What have you done? BTW the OP code already works fine, I have tested it

Comment: Sorry, not good enough. OP code already works, therefore you are not identifying the problem

Comment: Because nobody has yet to give a valid answer. Fact is, his code works because I tested it. So posting a different way to do the same thing is not going to help, because likely his problem is due to something else.